# R Shiny Selectize: How to set the minimum number of options in selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I am trying to increase the length of the dropdown list when using selectizeInput in Shiny.

I know I can set the max number of items shown by: `options = list(maxOptions = n)` but how could I define a minimum number of options?

Comment: Instead of minimum number of options, I think you might be asking the minimal _height_ of the selectize input?

Comment: My target is to increase the size of the dropdown list. I believe that this would be achieved if I could either increase the minimal height of the selectize input (as you suggest) or if I could define a minimum number of options.

Comment: There is no minimum number of options in selectize input: it just shows all available options, subject to the constraint of `maxOptions`. I guess you might be able to change its height using CSS. I have not tried, though.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue about setting the minimum number of options?

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, there is no minimum number of options setting, at least none that I know of. However, since you're trying to increase the length of the dropdown, you can just do that with CSS.

Suppose this is your dropdown:

```
  selectizeInput("select", "Select multiple options",
             choices = LETTERS, multiple = T
             ),
```

Just add:

```
  tags$style(type='text/css', 
         ".selectize-dropdown-content {
                                       max-height: 600px; ## CHANGE THIS
                                       }"
         )
```

And you get:

[image: long]

As a minimal example, try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectizeInput("select", "Select multiple options",
                 choices = LETTERS, multiple = T
                 ),
  tags$style(type='text/css', 
             ".selectize-dropdown-content {
                                           max-height: 600px; 
                                           }"
             )   
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```